# Отделение логики приложения от Swing-потока

Tags: java, база-данных, многопоточность, swing

Добрый день. Я пишу приложение с графическим интерфейсом используя Swing. По нажатию кнопки мне необходимо обращаться к базе данных (допустим, получить все записи из таблицы). И, чтобы интерфейс был интерактивен во время запроса, мне необходимо исполнять действия с БД в отдельном потоке. Пока что мне в голову пришла только одна мысль : по нажатию определенной кнопки запускать новый поток так

```
 someButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
       new Thread(() -> {}); // в теле лямбды написать метод для БД
 })
```

Можно ли сделать лучше?

Comment: Гляньте на SwingWorker https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем случае, очень подойдет абстрактный класс [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) в нем присутствуют методы для обработки в background-е, а так же методы по завершению работы.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте CompleteableFuture. Запустили, получили результат, в обработчике сделали invokeLater в UI поток с результатом.